# Use of vals and accessing elements directly in scala

Tags: scala

Is there trade off between directly accessing data(Which has other data) from a val and reassigning this data to another val.
Say, we have

`case class User( name : String, id:Int)`

And we try to access the name multiple times in method using:

```
def someMethod()={
println(User.name)
println(s"The user name is $User.name")
}
```

So I had couple of questions:
1) Would be there be any performance issues one way or the other assuming we access it multiple times ?
2) Any good reason for choosing one way over the other say in terms of readability, best practice and similar aspects.

Comment: There are no performance issues when accessing `u.name` multiple times. It is same as `u.getName()` in java.

Comment: Under the hood, a case class is a POJO with getters and setters given to you after your code is compiled. So you are effectively calling the getName method!